# How to instantiate seamless scrolling tiles

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, arcade

I'm trying to create in Unity an "Endless Runner" game, where the player remains stationary on the 0 of the axes while the tiles underneath him scroll with a fixed speed on the Z-Axis.
The script attached spawns 5 tiles at the start while already scrolling at the speed set in the `GameManager` and then keeps on spawning tiles based on a timer.

The issue I'm facing is the following:

The tiles that are spawned with the timer are too much distant from the starting set of tiles.

How can I calculate the correct distance between the set of the already scrolling tiles and those the script start to spawn after 5 seconds in order to have seamless scrolling?

I'm attaching the script with what I've written so far in the hope that someone knows how to proceed, or perhaps knows a different method. Thanks!

```
public class TileManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform player;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] tilesArray;
    [SerializeField] private int tilesToSpawn = 5;
    [SerializeField] private float zPosSpawn = 0f;
    [SerializeField] private float tileLength = 20f;

    public List<GameObject> tilesList;
    private float spawnRate;
    private float timeSinceLastSpawned;

    void Start()
    {
        //scrollingSpeed is -5
        spawnRate = GameManager.Instance.scrollingObjectsSpeed * -1;
        StartSpawnLogic();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        timeSinceLastSpawned += Time.deltaTime;
        SpawnTimer();
        DestroyAfterSpawn();
        
    }

    
    private void StartSpawnLogic()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tilesToSpawn; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    SpawnTiles(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    SpawnTiles(Random.Range(0, tilesArray.Length));
                }
            }
        }

    //SPAWN FUNCTION
    private void SpawnTiles(int tileIndex)
    {
        //On Instantiation a list is filled to later dispose of the tiles after they reached a certain point
        tilesList.Add((GameObject)Instantiate(tilesArray[tileIndex], transform.forward * zPosSpawn, Quaternion.identity));
        zPosSpawn += tileLength;
    }

    //TIMER
    private void SpawnTimer()
    {
        if (timeSinceLastSpawned >= spawnRate)
        {
            timeSinceLastSpawned = 0;
            SpawnTiles(Random.Range(1, tilesArray.Length));
        }
    }

    void RemoveObjFromList(GameObject tile)
    {
        Destroy(tile);
        tilesList.Remove(tile);
    }

    private void DestroyAfterSpawn()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tilesList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (tilesList[i].transform.position.z <= -20f)
            {
                RemoveObjFromList(tilesList[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is a lot more complicated than it needs to be.  The dependencies on GameManager, speed, TileManager's transform, hard coded values, spawn-rate, and timing are all unnecessary.  I suggest taking a look a this free tutorial published by Unity: https://learn.unity.com/project/unit-3-sound-and-effects

Comment: Thanks Jim, your answer helped me to understand that I don't need to spawn the whole tiles but only the obstacles while keeping just one tile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, here is one way. All you need to do is move the transform.position of gameobject attached to the background sprite.

at a set speed at Time.DeldaTime, something like this (in Update()):

```
transform.position.x -= speed * Time.DeltaTime
```

Then add an if loop to catch when the bounds of the background reach a point.
This is an example, basically - when the background reaches said point - change the transform.position to equal a fixed position on the other side of the screen.

```
if(tranfom.position <= -50x){
    transform.position = new Vector2(50, 0, 0,)
}
```